# Python Kivy - Manually refresh the app after the configs are changed

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have tried using the on_config_change method but i can't seem to make it work. What I came up with is creating a singleton to hold the instance of the configurations and always change that but even like that i can't trigger the on_config_change:

The Settings with the ColorPicker:

```
class ColorPickerContent(FloatLayout):
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def _cancel(self):
        return self.cancel()

    def _save_color(self, hex_code):
        AppConfigs().config.set('section1', 'text_color', hex_code)
        AppConfigs().config.write()
        return self.cancel()


class SettingButtons(SettingItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_release')
        super(SettingItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for aButton in kwargs["buttons"]:
            oButton = Button(text=aButton['title'], font_size='15sp')
            oButton.ID = aButton['id']
            self.add_widget(oButton)
            oButton.bind(on_release=self.On_ButtonPressed)

    def set_value(self, section, key, value):
        # set_value normally reads the configparser values and runs on an error
        # to do nothing here
        return

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def On_ButtonPressed(self, instance):
        content = ColorPickerContent(cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Get Color", content=content,
                            size_hint=(1, 1), auto_dismiss=True)
        self._popup.open()
```

The Kivy file for the ColorPickerContent:

```
<ColorPickerContent>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        ColorPicker:
            id: color_source

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Close"
                on_release: root._cancel()
            Button:
                id: btn_save
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root._save_color(color_source.hex_color)
```

Basically I want 1 of my text inputs to change after the option is changed. The color is changed but only after I restart the app. Any ideas what i could do?